# Create Hyperlink for row each entry in Excel Sheet but just in specific columns

Tags: excel, search, hyperlink, vba

In the attached code, I am looping through all the Excel files in a folder and searching for a keyword.  I then extract the file name, sheet number, cell number and row data and place that information into a newly created spreadsheet called "Summary".  How do I hyperlink just the worksheet # and cell # columns (Columns B and C) to point to the exact file, page, cell where the newly created row entry came from?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
 ...
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a forlder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
  ...
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = wsReport
    xRow = 1
    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Test"
        ...
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsx")
        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else

                    xCount = xCount + 1
                    xRow = xRow + 1
                    .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                    .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                    .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                     WriteDetails rCellwsReport, xFound

                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Range("A1:A" & xCount + 1).Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With

    MsgBox xCount & "cells have been found", , "SUPERtools for Excel"
ExitHandler:
    Set xOut = Nothing
    ...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

Private Sub WriteDetails(ByRef xReceiver As Range, ByRef xDonor As Range)
  xReceiver.Value = xDonor.Parent.Name
  xReceiver.Offset(, 1).Value = xDonor.Address

  xDonor.EntireRow.Resize(, 100).Copy xReceiver.Offset(, 2)

  Set xReceiver = xReceiver.Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(xCount)` should be actual range for example `Range("A1")` or `Range("A" & i)` where you increment the `i` in the loop. Also `xWb.Name` should be `xWb.FullName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a hyperlink to an `external workbook/worksheet/cell` you need to understand how the link forms

See this example

Let's say you have a file `Joe.Xlsx` in `C:\`. And let's assume that it has a worksheet called `Sheet1` and you want to hyperlink to cell `A1` of that sheet.

So in your current workbook, you will type

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\Joe.xlsx]Sheet1!A1","CLICK HERE")
```

So if you break it, it will look like this.

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim SheetName As String
Dim CellAddress As String

FileName = "C:\Joe.xlsx"
SheetName = "Sheet1"
CellAddress = "A1"

If InStr(1, SheetName, " ") Then SheetName = "'" & SheetName & "'"

Range("A1").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & _
                      FileName & _
                      "]" & _
                      SheetName & _
                      "!" & _
                      CellAddress & _
                      Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & _
                      "CLICK HERE" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Simply use this in your code in a loop and create the hyperlinks

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code. it is difficult to read the code in comments

Comment: You suggestion however does not just make only column C the hyperlink??

Comment: The above code will help you create a link to a cell in an external workbook.

Comment: After clicking on the hyperlink created by your code, I get an error message of `Reference isn't valid`.

Comment: What do you see in the formula bar? What is the formula that you see?

Comment: `=HYPERLINK("[F:\Data\U028\U028_Excel\New folder\Data_Brd20_2017-05-18_16-13-45_627.xlsx]page 4!$F$12","$F$12")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145778/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-joe).